# cAdvisor не работает

Tags: docker, containers

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor-amd64:v0.47.0
    container_name: cadvisor
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg:/dev/kmsg
    ports:
      - 8585:8585
```

Не открывается из браузера по ип:порт. Фаервола нет.

Comment: А вы уверены что он запускается на 8585? На https://github.com/google/cadvisor написано, что 8080.

Comment: Да. 

    ports:
      - 8585:8585

Comment: ports не означает на каком порту запускается cAdvisor, а только говорит, какой порт открыть (publish) для доступа из внешней сети, если вы укажете 8585, а фактически оно запускается на 8080, то оно работать не будет

Comment: спасибо. решил проблему) Теперь композ выглядит так:

version: '3.7'

services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor-amd64:v0.47.0
    container_name: cadvisor
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg:/dev/kmsg
    ports:
      - 8585:8585
    command:
    - '-port=8585'